# Simplify: $\sum_{k=1}^n ({n \choose k}k^2 )$

Tags: combinatorics

I need to simplify: $\sum_{k=1}^n ({n \choose k}k^2 )$.  My first idea was to get rid of the square and use known identities to proceed. This is what I did 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n( {n \choose k}k^2) = \sum_{k=1}^n( \frac n k {n-1 \choose k-1}k^2) = \sum_{k=1}^n {n-1 \choose k-1} nk = n \sum_{k=1}^n {n-1 \choose k-1} k = \\ n \sum_{s=0}^n \left({n-1 \choose s}(s+1) \right)$$
Now, the only thing that stops me here is the $s+1$ factor. Is there a way to dispose of it, or maybe to change it to $s$?

Comment: Split it into two sums, one with the $s$ factor, the other with the $1$ factor.

Comment: Differentiate $\sum_k \binom{n}{k}x^k$

Comment: i deleted my answer since it is redundant. See the contribution of @LeonBloy in the link given above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

You reached $$n \sum_{s=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose s}(s+1)$$
Let's continue 
$$n \sum_{s=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose s}(s+1) = n \left[\sum_{s=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose s}(s)+ \sum_{s=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose s}\right]$$
$$=n \left[(n-1)\sum_{s=1}^{n-1} {n-2 \choose {s-1}}+ \sum_{s=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose s} \right]$$
By binomial theorem

$$=n[(n-1)2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}]$$
$$=n(n+1).2^{n-2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint : $$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}k^2 =\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}k(k-1)+ \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}k$$
And if you write 
$$ P(x)= \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k= (1+x)^n -1$$
You will have : 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}k^2 =P''(1)+P'(1)$$

Comment: How did you get the HINT?

Comment: @Aemilius: you mean the idea of it?

Comment: Yes. but I think that I already see it. I just had to take a closer look at this - it's simple.